# In C, why initializing pointer to 0 doesn't give compile time error?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I was playing around with pointers, and I tried to initialize a pointer variable with a value and not a memory location.

If I am initializing a pointer with a non-zero value, and it is clearly giving me a compile time error.

```
int *p = 1;
main.c:14:14: error: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
 int *p = 1;
          ^
```

However, if I initialize it as value 0, it doesn't give me a compile time error.

```
int *p = 0; //no compile time error but segmentation fault
```

Why is this so? Is there a valid memory address like 0? Normally, an address location is shown as  `0xffffff` or similar way. How is 0 interpreted into a memory location?

Thanks

Comment: Compatibility:  0 is the way NULL pointers has historically been definined

Comment: Thank you @Soren. If 0 is a null pointer, why is it segmentation faulting? If I am printing it, shouldn't it ideally show `(null)` instead of a segfault?

Comment: How are you printing it?

Comment: How are you printing it?

Comment: `NULL` (usually `0`) is a specific value to say the pointer has no valid value - as opposed to an unintialised arbitrary value. That is expected and legal, until you dereference it at run-time.

Comment: I am printing it as `printf("%i", *p);`

Comment: Print the pointer with `printf("%p", (void*)p);`

Comment: @init The expression `*p` dereferences the pointer. On a null pointer, it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: You are dereferencing it, not printing it's value. And dereferencing an invalid pointer is UB.

Comment: Thank you Everyone.

Comment: Without dereferencing, a MCVE consisting only of `int main()
{
int *p = 0;
return 0;
}`, compiled with `clang` reports no runtime errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to assign 0 to a pointer because `NULL` is typically defined as 0 cast to a `void *`.  Any other integer value is a type mismatch.

While you can cast some other integer value to a pointer to assign it a value, it rarely makes sense to do so unless you're dealing with an embedded environment where specific memory locations have known uses.

You're getting a segfault not because you're printing the pointer but because you *dereference* the pointer and attempt to print what it points to.  Because the pointer has a `NULL` value, dereferencing it causes undefined behavior.  In this case, it results in a segfault.

To print the pointer, do the following:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)p);
```

Answer (score 4):

From the C11 Standard (draft):

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> [...]
>
> **3** An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
>   `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a
>   pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal
>   to a pointer to any object or function.

Answer (score 3):

Usualy `0` represent a "no address" as`NULL`. When you use it that way you can check:

```
if (p) {
     doSomthingWith(*p)
}
```

Comment: @ohad-eytan If 0 is a null pointer, why is it segmentation faulting? If I am printing it, shouldn't it ideally show (null) instead of a segfault?

Comment: @init you're trying to print `p` or `*p`?

Comment: Sometimes 0 is a perfectly valid address.

Comment: @EugeneSh. like 0x00000 ?

Comment: @init It doesn't matter how you write it. Zero is zero.

Answer (score 1):

A literal `0` in a pointer context represents a null pointer constant. A `1` is always just a `1` and therefore an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this so? Is there a valid memory address like 0? Normally, an
>   address location is shown as 0xffffff or similar way. How is 0
>   interpreted into a memory location?

Generally, the address 0 is not accessible for most of the operating systems, because they reserve it for other tasks.

In C, the address 0 is interpreted as a NULL pointer and a NULL pointer is a pointer that is interpreted as a pointer that is not referencing a valid memory location accessible by the program.
So, if you are defining `int* p = 0` or `int* p = NULL` the program written in C is assuming that the pointer is pointing to nothing (not a `0xffffff` address).

Comment: Nitpicking: The official notation is "null pointer", which you get if assigning `NULL` (or just `0`) to a pointer variable.